# ErrorException Trying to get property 'password_hash' of non-object in myth-auth Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

ErrorException
Trying to get property 'password_hash' of non-object
VENDORPATH\myth\auth\src\Authentication\LocalAuthenticator.php at line 165

165         if (! Password::verify($password, $user->password_hash))

Comment: Show us how you defined the `$user` variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)