# ErrorException Trying to get property 'password_hash' of non-object

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Im fairly sure this is a configuration issue on my end, but Im relatively new and not sure where to look or what information to provide to troubleshoot.

I am able to create users, but when I attempt to login, I get this error.

I'm running codeigniter 4, and have disabled the email authorization, and limited the password validation (same error no matter what's blocked out there) public $requireActivation = null; public $activeResetter = null;

```
    'Myth\Auth\Authentication\Passwords\CompositionValidator',
    //'Myth\Auth\Authentication\Passwords\NothingPersonalValidator',
    //'Myth\Auth\Authentication\Passwords\DictionaryValidator',
    // 'Myth\Auth\Authentication\Passwords\PwnedValidator',
];
```

Everything else seems to work well, trying to test login redirection right now, but cant get past this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bbAZ.png)

Comment: My suggestion is on line 158 don't do `(!$user)` but do `(!is_object($user))` as it looks like you are expecting that and not filtering it out. The error you're getting is because `$user` is not an object it is something else.

Comment: Why are you asking this **same** [question the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71853740/errorexception-trying-to-get-property-password-hash-of-non-object-in-myth-auth)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ErrorException Trying to get property 'password\_hash' of non-object in myth-auth Codeigniter 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71853740/errorexception-trying-to-get-property-password-hash-of-non-object-in-myth-auth)